# Движение двух объектов (actor) одновременно при касании экрана

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
public void create() {

//код

stage = new Stage();

stage.addActor(tank); // оба танка наследуются от 1 класса
stage.addActor(tank2);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

рендер

```
public void render() {
//код
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
stage.draw();
//код
}
```

оба actor отображаются, но реагирует на нажатие лишь tank2.

**Как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии 1 пальцем оба actor'а реагировали одновременно?**

Пробовал InputMultiplexer, но так они реагируют на нажатия 2 пальцами (причем каждый actor на 1 палец по очереди).

---

в описании к классу Stage:

If an actor handles an event by returning true from the input method, then the stage's input method will also return true, causing subsequent InputProcessors to not receive the event.

Если actor обработал событие, возвращая истину от input method, то  input method класса Stage также возвратит истину, в результате последующий InputProcessors не получит событие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно просто добавить один и тот же InputListener и тому, и другому объекту.

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно что-то такое:

```
InputListener myListener = new InputListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        // Двигаем объекты
        tank.move();
        tank2.move();

        return true; // Говорим, что нажатие было обработано
    }
};
tank.addListener(myListener);
tank2.addListener(myListener);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас они работают синхронно(первый tank повторяет за tank2). А как сделать, чтоб каждый двигался независимо друг от друга? То есть, если они находятся слева и справа экрана, и при нажатии например в центр, нужно чтобы они оба двигались в центр со своих позиций..

Comment: @RuslMag измените код функции - он может быть любым. Это по сути совсем другой вопрос

Comment: Понял, спасибо что помогли с вопросом. Буду пробовать